# Unable to delete .exe file after uninstalling windows service through c#

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am using `System.Configuration.Install.ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper` to install and uninstall windows service within another service. The problem is when service is installed, `exe` of service is locked or something but I need to delete service files after service is uninstalled.

Service install:

```
System.Configuration
      .Install
      .ManagedInstallerClass
      .InstallHelper(new string[] { "/i", serviceExePath });
```

Service Uninstall:

```
System.Configuration
      .Install
      .ManagedInstallerClass
      .InstallHelper(new string[] { "/u", serviceExePath });
```

[Error description while trying to delete exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sy0T.png)

Comment: `exe of service is locked or something` how did you come up with this hypothesis, did you get an error message, if you got an error message please paste it, how are you trying to delete the exe, paste the code. Please think of this from our point of view, we have no idea what you are writing an how, we cant see your code or error messages. Try to help us help you

Comment: I am try to delete it manually and error message is saying that "The action can't be completed because the file is open in ShoppervalueUtility. ShoppervalueUtility is our installer service.

Comment: Does that utility program reference the .exe file as an assembly?

Comment: No both are separate and we are just serviceExePath to install or uninstall. Service install and uninstall process is successful but unable to delete service exe while utility (service installer) is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue. It turns out that the `ManageInstallerClass` puts a File Handle lock on the service and you can't delete it until the locking process terminates.

I got around this using the following code:

```
    var s = new ServiceInstaller
    {
        Context = new InstallContext(),
        ServiceName = "<YOUR SERVICE NAME>"
    };
    s.Uninstall(null);
```

After the `ServiceInstaller` finishes you should be able to delete the service file.

To use the `ServiceInstaller` you'll have to include `System.ServiceProcess` in your class.